# Why Constant first in an if condition

Tags: javascript

I often see if structures being coded like this:

```
if (true == a)
if (false == a)
```

Why do they put the constant value first and not the variable? as in this example:

```
if (a == true)
if (b == true)
```

Comment: [Yoda Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions)

Comment: Why taged to `C` I got confuse :(

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan the same law works on C also.Putting constant on left of comparison operator is good and avoids accidental assignments.

Comment: @Dayalrai didn't notice that I confuse because of `===` then I notice `var` then I notice `javascript` then I found I am not wrong the question is tagged to C unnecessarily. :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Ye sorry my bad :P i should have made it more general code like ^^

Comment: Update: Edited so it is more general ^^

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan yes if you are talking about syntax specifically then you are right.

Comment: Note that even in other languages where the `=` operator is used for both assignment and comparison depending on context (and you can't do an assignment in an if condition) it is still a matter of personal style whether you put the constant on the left or the right. (Also `if (1 == a)` might be a better example to keep it general because if you're testing a boolean you have a third option: `if (a)`...)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is called yoda syntax or yoda conditions.

It is used to help prevent accidental assignments.

If you forget an equals sign it will fail

`if(false = $a)` fails to compile

`if($a = true)` assigns the value of `true` to the variable `$a` and evaluates as `true`

The [Wordpress Coding Standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#yoda-conditions) mention this specifically:

```
if ( true == $the_force ) {
    $victorious = you_will( $be );
}
```

> When doing logical comparisons, always put the variable on the right
>   side, constants or literals on the left.
>
> In the above example, if you omit an equals sign (admit it, it happens
>   even to the most seasoned of us), you’ll get a parse error, because
>   you can’t assign to a constant like true. If the statement were the
>   other way around ( $the_force = true ), the assignment would be
>   perfectly valid, returning 1, causing the if statement to evaluate to
>   true, and you could be chasing that bug for a while.
>
> A little bizarre, it is, to read. Get used to it, you will.

Comment: Though it is good to prevent typos you will have a lack of readability.

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 - one minor nit-pick. An evaluation operation returns the value being assigned, so `if ($a = false)` will assign $a to false, but will also evaluate to _false_, not true.

Answer (score -2):

This is an example of `YODA Style` of coding

```
if (var a == true){
 }
```

is less safer than

```
 if (true == var a){
 }
```

because when you forget that second `=` mark, you'll get an invalid assignment error, and can catch it at *compile time*.

Comment: You mean the second is safer right.

Comment: @Sankalp Mishra Please read your answer again.I am sure you will get to know where to edit.